# python: override __new__ on polymorphic class

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to override **new** on a polymorphic class, and if so how?

Comment: can someone explain me whats wrong with this question?

Comment: no i'm not kidding, because when i posted the question, the system responded with that... and it was obvious it was a matter of text length. It was the only way to get the question submited and as i think it is a pertinent suscint and objective question it was my way of calling some attention that the filter criteria is a bit poor to decide over question quality, specially based on text length.

Comment: Generally, you want to show that you've made at least some effort to solve the problem or answer the question you're having for yourself and that means a certain amount of text. The minimum doesn't guarantee quality, but anything less has a good chance of not meeting standards, so it's an automated way to help keep the quality of questions higher on average. It's one thing to disagree with the policy and explain that, but it's another entirely to essentially mock the system and then wonder what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to override `new` on a polymorphic class.

Comment: what should be added to this question:
"Is it possible to override new on a polymorphic class, and if so how?" to make it acceptable

Comment: @neu-rah: In which case I add "`def __new___(meta, classname, bases, classDict):`" *All* classes in Python 3 are polymorphic in some sense. This question is trivial and trivially answerable. Do you have some sort of actual problem? Then try to ask a question related to that.

Comment: thank you for your attencion,upvoted that.
As my  __new__ overloads call a super class to do the allocation and further i return that. On a polymorphic class what super class should i call to allocate the object, the allocated object wont be missing some initialization from other classes? or shloud i call all super news (makes no sense to me)?

Comment: @neu-rah: So, forget the "polymorphic class". As mentioned, in Python, all classes are polymorphic in some sense, as they all subclass from `object`. Then take the rest of your question, add code examples, and pose that as a new question. Because that question is a valid question.